# How to generate new permutations in Python?

Tags: python, permutation

I have a question; probably the answer is easy but I couldn't find out.

I created a function and it is working correctly.

```
x = 100
y = 100
A = (x ,y)
```

Since I have manually defined x and y there is no problem here; but the thing is, I want all the possible (x, y) permutations tried in the function.Let's assume:

```
B = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), ...(99,99)]
```

So how can I make an iteration as:

```
for i in B:
    i == A
```

This might be a bad approach but I believe you understand my intention.

Thanks from now.

Edit:

This is the function:

```
K = []
L = []
M = []

def F():

    x = 100
    y = 100

    A = (x, y)

    for i in range(1, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            K.append((i))

    for j in range(1, y):
        if y % j == 0:
            L.append((j))

    P = sum(K[0:])
    R = sum(L[0:])

    if P == y and R == x:
        M.append(A)

    print(K, L)
    print(M)

F()
```

Comment: Where/what exactly is your function?

Comment: Sorry for my English level.What I want to say is, I have to give values for x and y manually.I need them automated for a specified range.

Comment: You don't want permutations (which are the possible orderings of *n* objects). You simply want the product of the set `{1, 2, ..., 99}` with itself (or possibly the set of 2-item combinations, it's not clear from your example of `B`)

Comment: Use `for combination in itertools.product(range(1, 100), repeat=2): ...`. I'm not sure if it's intended, but your function modifies global variables, so running it more than once will not work as you probably expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You want either a product:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(range(1,5), repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

or a list of combinations (only if `x == y`):

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(1,5), 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

or if `x` and `y` are different:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(range(1,5), range(1,4)))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: The first one is what I need.But how can I make the relation between A(x, y) and the product list? I mean how can I make a loop for A? A(1) = (1,1); A(2) = (1,2); A(3) = (1,3)... and so on?

Comment: `enumerate(product(...))`?